# Deleting a void pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers

I've been tasked to fix some possible bugs in our project and found that a void pointer is being deleted in one of the functions.

I know you're not supposed to delete a void pointer and that you have to cast it back to its original type before deleting it so that it is properly destructed. However, the code is as follows:

```
void someFunction () {
    void *a[2] = {NULL, NULL};
    initializeFunction(a+0);
    initializeFunction(a+1);
    ...
    //do something
    ...
    delete a[0];
    delete a[1];
}

initializeFunction(void** b) {
    *b = new unsigned char [size]; //size is calculated based on all the types and how many of each are used in innerFunction()
    innerFunction((char *)*b);
}

innerFunction(char * x) {
    *((int *)x) = intValue;
    *((double *)(x += sizeof(int))) = doubleValue;
    *((SomeClass *)(x += sizeof(doubleValue))) = aSomeClassObject;
    *((AnotherClass *)(x += sizeof(aSomeClassObject))) = anAnotherClassObject;
}
```

I wasn't sure how to approach this as I've never encountered such usage. I'm confused with all the casts and the variety of types being saved. That `innerFunction` had more types in the actual code. (Though maybe it's worth noting that aside from the primitive data types, all user-defined classes used only had array member variables.)

In order to delete `a`, is it as simple as casting it to `(unsigned char*)`? Or does this not work because technically there are different types within the memory pointed to by `a`? Will I have to do the delete equivalent of `innerFunction()`?

Comment: My recommendation: run as fast as you can away from this code. It's got undefined behavior all over the place. If this is indicative of the quality of the code base, it's likely beyond the point of fixability.

Comment: I think the programer thought he was deleting a dynamic array :)

Comment: @JasonR I would if I could. :( There are plans to refactor the code but it's going to be difficult...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, change this code to use a `struct` containing all the necessary subobjects.

If we just go ahead and check that all the types used are POD and blindly assume there are no alignment issues and that the compiler isn't falling into any strict aliasing traps, then yes, you can change the deletes to

```
delete[] static_cast<unsigned char*>(a[0]);
delete[] static_cast<unsigned char*>(a[1]);
```

and have slightly safer behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with deleting void pointers is that destuctors are not called. So if you have a function that returns a owned pointer, you should have a function that destroys it as well.